# How to add two texts on iPhone splash screen using animations

Tags: iphone, ios

In my application splash screen, I want to do some animation like moving of text from,

1. **Text1**: Move from left to right.
2. **Text2**: Move from right to left.

How to add both the texts in middle of the splash screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can animate any UIElement:

```
//create UILabel
UILabel* textLeft = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:textLeft];
textLeft.text = @"LEFT TEXT";
//get current position and size
CGRect targetFrame = textLeft.frame;
//change X coord to desired position
targetFrame.origin.x = 300.0f;
//animate
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{textLeft.frame = targetFrame;}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But please give me any sample code.i have getting small confusion about your answer.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Setup a view in storyboard for example - create 2 textfield in starting position. Label them like proposed @"firstLabel". Than use code I pasted on viewDidLoad to initialize animations.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski above code only for animating the labels but doesn't explain how to add two textfields at the applaunch .

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski i am trying to post your code.But Animation will not be getting.

Comment: UILabel *textLeft = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:@"firstLabel"];
    //get current position and size
    CGRect targetFrame = textLeft.frame;
    //change X coord to desired position
    targetFrame.origin.x = 300.0f;
    //animate
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{textLeft.frame = targetFrame;}];
    
    UILabel *textRight=(UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:@"SecondLabel"];
    
    CGRect targetFrame1=textRight.frame;
    targetFrame1.origin.x=300.0f;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{textRight.frame=targetFrame1;}];

Comment: This is my code.I am menctioning the above code in ViewDidLoad

Comment: Check code in my answer updated - I think you didn't tag it properly in builder. So I changed a code to create label for you.

Answer (score 1):

We can't add any customization in the splash screen directly.The below idea could be helpful to you, don't put splash screen in the app . First add one `ViewController` (It is having two textfields and animations) to the window. After completion of animation try to remove the viewcontroller and do the rest .

1 . Create one viewcontroller called animatetext.h,.m .

2 . In the animatetext.m viewdidload method write the textfield animation code .

3 . Next in the  appdelegate didfinishlaunchingwithoptions write the code like self.window.rootviewcontroller = animatetextobject.

4 . After that In the animateview class call one method (like removeView) after 20seconds (Animationduration of textfields) . In the removeView method write `[self.view removeFromSuperView]`;and below that line add `[appdelegate.window setRootViewController:someViewController];`

Comment: @MR.Tendulkar please give me any example.I have little bit confusion.Thank you